# how to set webservice url properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a ASP.NET application. Inside the asp.net application I have a folder called WebServices  where I keep all the .asmx files.

I am referring these asmx files inside asp.net .cs files. Instead of giving the full url to the webservice.url property how can i set the path like this.

```
 ds.Url = this.ResolveUrl("~/WebServices/xxx.asmx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) what you're looking for?

```
ds.Url = Server.MapPath("~/WebServices/xxx.asmx");
```

You can get hold of it either via `Server` property in `Page` class, or via `HttpContext.Current.Server` chain.

Even better, I'd store this URL in an application configuration file.

Comment: Server.MapPath refers to the physical path. so it's throws an exception. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions suggests that you have your webservices in the same project as the consuming apllication. This will not work. Move all your webservices into a seperate project.

Answer (score 0):

If your services and cs files both are in same project then you donot need to set the URL as such. These services can be called as if you can call other classes in your application.